# How to get indices of an element from a vector of vectors in Scala?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, scala-3

I have this data structure encoding a presence/absence of an element in a plane:

```
val rows = Vector(
  Vector("-", "-", "-", "-"),
  Vector("-", "-", "X", "-"),
  Vector("-", "-", "-", "-"))
```

I want to get a pair of coordinates of "X". Suppose that the upper left corner is `(0,0)`.

I tried to get the result by for comprehension like so:

```
for
  row <- rows
  rowIndex <- 0 until rows.length
  colIndex = row.indexOf("X")
  if (colIndex > -1)
yield (rowIndex, colIndex)
```

This correctly finds the `colIndex`, but I need to somehow bind the `rowIndex` to the particular `row`. Now, it iterates over the `row` with the element independently, rows.length times.

Secondary question:
If there are more than one element, we are looking for, how to make it stop searching after finding the first one? Result should be just a pair `(row, col)`.

Answer (score 3):

Taking advantage that **Vectors** have fast access by index you can do this:

```scala
def firstIndexWhere[A](data: Vector[Vector[A]])(cond: A => Boolean): Option[(Int, Int)] =
  Iterator.range(start = 0, end = data.length).flatMap { i =>
    Iterator.range(start = 0, end = data(i).length).map { j =>
      (i, j)
    }
  } find {
    case (i, j) =>
      cond(data(i)(j))
  }
```

This will effectively stop at the first successful index.

Another approach may be:

```scala
def firstIndexWhere[A](data: Vector[Vector[A]])(cond: A => Boolean): Option[(Int, Int)] =
  data.iterator.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (row, i) =>
      row.iterator.zipWithIndex.collecFirst {
        case (elem, j) if (cond(elem)) => (i, j)
      }
  } collectFirst {
    case Some(indexes) => indexes
  }
```

Comment: Could you make a for comprehension from that?

Comment: @pogurek For the first one yes, you can do `val indeces = for { i <- Iterator.range(start = 0, end = data.length); j <- Iterator.range(start = 0, end = data(i).length) } yield (i, j)` and then call `indeces.find { case (i, j) => cond(data(i)(j)) }` but I don't think is worth it.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I came up with this solution: `for
  row <- rows.zipWithIndex
  rowIndex = row._2
  colIndex = row._1.indexOf("X")
  if (colIndex > -1)
yield (rowIndex, colIndex)`  Do you think is noticably more inefficient than your explixit map/flatMap approach?

Comment: @pogurek you can do `for { case (row, rowIndex) <- rows.zipWithInde` also note such solution will collect all indexes and will perform multiple iterations so not really efficient.

Answer (score 2):

One option is a purely recursive method:

```
def findIndex2D[T](v: Vector[Vector[T]], value: T): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
  val outSize = v.size
  val inSize = v.headOption.fold(0)(_.size)

  def loop(outer: Int, inner: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] =
    if (outer >= outSize) {
      None
    } else if (inner >= inSize) {
      loop(outer + 1, 0)
    } else if (rows(outer)(inner) == value) {
      Some((outer, inner))
    } else {
      loop(outer, inner + 1)
    }

  loop(0, 0)
}
```

Or perhaps a hybrid:

```
def findIndex2D[T](v: Vector[Vector[T]], value: T): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
  def loop(outer: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] =
    if (outer >= v.size) {
      None
    } else {
      val inner = rows(outer).indexOf(value)
      if (inner >= 0) {
        Some((outer, inner))
      } else {
        loop(outer + 1)
      }
    }

  loop(0)
}
```

I'll leave the reader to decide whether either of these is better than a solution using only built-in functions. They are a good starting point for more complex searches (e.g. find nth matching value)